# Check whether list is null or not in CSOM?

Tags: development, csom

I have developed a code in CSOM(Client Side Object Module) using **c#** where before performing any operation on the list I want to check whether the list is null or not?
In SSOM we can check that by

`.TryGetList()` method

how I can achieve the same in CSOM.

`if(list!= null){....}`
 is not working as it always goes into the if condition and throws the error in `context.Update()`

Is there any other way to achieve this without putting the

`if(list!= null){....}` into `try-catch`.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it doesn't exist in native CSOM, but the PnP Core library has this extension method:

```
 if (ctx.Web.ListExists("My List")){
            //do something
 }
```

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core

Answer (score 1):

You can check the list collection count to see if the list exists in the site as shown below:

```
           ListCollection listCollection = clientContext.Web.Lists; 
           clientContext.Load(listCollection, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title).Where(list => list.Title == "ListName"));

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            if (listCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                Response.Write("List  exists...");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("List does not exist");
            }
```

Comment: It's not happening. Still its goes into the loop and gives error.